# swift filter array by date

Tags: arrays, swift, date, filter

I have a JSON like this

```json
[
  {
    "place": "somewhere",
    "dateStart": "2017-02-25+01:00",
    "name": "name of the event",
    "dateEnd": "2017-06-18+02:00",
    "region": "region 1"
  },
  {
    "place": "another place",
    "dateStart": "2017-03-25+01:00",
    "name": "another name",
    "dateEnd": "2017-08-18+02:00",
    "region": "region 2"
  },
  ...
]

    ]
```

the format of "dateStart" and "dateEnd" is String

I parsed it with swiftyjson

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsPath = try! fileManager.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let filePath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("events.json")
        let url = filePath
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        if data != nil {
            stringJson = JSON(data: data!)
        }
        
        guard let json = stringJson.array else { return }
```

I can filter this array with:

```
let filteredArrayByRegion = json.filter{$0["region"].string == "region name"}
```

but now I want to filter the array by "dateEnd" and I want the records which have "dateEnd" greater than "today".

I understand that I have to convert the string ["dateEnd"].string in date but I'm not able to create the closure to filter the array.

Can anyone put me on the right track?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Parse the strings into dates, and compare them to today.

Comment: I try:`code` let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" and then:  `code`  let eventiRegionaliPerData = json.filter { json in return dateFormatter.date(from: json["eventoDataFine"].string!)! >= Date() }

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: @GiuseppeSala Don't post code in comments. Please [edit] your question with all relevant information.

Comment: "i want the records which have `dateEnd` greater than 'today'" ... So, if today's date in your location is "2017-07-24+06:00", is "2017-07-24+07:00" to be "greater than today"? It's a bit unusual to see timezone adjustments for date strings (sure, for datetime strings, but less common for date strings). Or do you want to consider those the "same as today", despite the time zone changes? Or is that `+01:00` in your example not a time zone change, but rather the hour and minute? If so, that's very strange to use `+` rather than `T` in that string. And then what time zone are those date strings?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, my My attempt did't work so I thought It was not necessary. i promise. I will be more careful in the future

Comment: @Alexander thank you for your suggest, my code doesn't work

Comment: @Rob, yes, I think I understand your observations and i'm evaluating how to use them

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @GiuseppeSala - So, what precisely does the +1:00 in that string represent? GMT+1 or 1:00am? And if 1:00am, in what timezone? The answer to this question changes completely based upon what that string is representing and it's unclear from the question.

Comment: @rob hi rob, i don't know, i think it's just 1:00am in italy

Comment: You should confirm with whomever wrote the web service, because it looks more like a timezone to me e.g. that from November through March, Italy's timezone is UTC+1. It matters, because it changes how your parse this.

Comment: @rob i'll try to ask to the web service, that is a government organization, i hope it answers :-)

Comment: If this is a proper web service, they might have official documentation that outlines precisely what this field contains.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would need to convert the date strings into `Date` instances and then you can compare those `Date` instances to `Date()` ("now").

But the strings you have are in a format that can be compared as strings. So you can get today's date as a string in the same format, then compare each of the `dateEnd` strings against the "now" string. This string comparison only works on very specific date/time formats and your strings happen to be in that format.

I'm assuming that the value after the `+` in your `dateEnd` strings is the time and not a timezone offset.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm"
let nowString = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Now you can use `nowString` in your filter:

```
let results = someArray.filter { ($0["dateEnd"] ?? "") > nowString }
```

where `someArray` is your array of dictionary.